# Calculate the Fourier Coefficient for $\ x^2 sin(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I really need help. I want to calculate the Fourier Coefficient for the function defined by: 
$\phi(x) = \ x^2 sin(x)$ 
 for: $\ x<0<4.81$

 I have a problem with the first step.

1. `FourierSinCoefficient[\[Phi][x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]`

Can anyone give me a clue how to do it?

Comment: Is this a mathematics question or a `Mathematica` question? `FourierSinCoefficient[x^2*Sin[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]` seems to work for me:

$$ -\frac{4 \sqrt{2 \pi } (-1)^n n}{\left(n^2-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: This is problem with mathematics. Generally I think there is a problem with `FourierParameters` but I can not to find it. In next step i try to calculate Fourier Series u[x_, t_]